# pyglet resolution of screen into variables

Tags: python-2.7, screen-resolution, pyglet

is there any options how to get values `height` and `width` of screen into variables using pyglet? I am able to print it but not extract these values.

```
import pyglet

platform = pyglet.window.get_platform()
display = platform.get_default_display()
screen = display.get_screens()
```

->

```
>>> screen
[XlibScreen(display=<pyglet.canvas.xlib.XlibDisplay object at 0x7f4644cf0990>, x=0, y=0, width=1366, height=768, xinerama=0)]
>>>
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it should be as simple as this:

```
platform = pyglet.window.get_platform()
display = platform.get_default_display()      
screen = display.get_default_screen()
screen_width = screen.width
screen_height = screen.height
```

Comment: Yes, now I see. Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

In new versions of `pyglet` pyglet.window.get_platform() is deprecated/removed [proof](https://web.archive.org/web/20180725142633/http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/modules/window.html#pyglet.window.get_platform)
Therefore code will look like:

```
    display = pyglet.canvas.Display()
    screen = display.get_default_screen()
    screen_width = screen.width
    screen_height = screen.height
```

Comment: Indeed, and see https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/canvas.html

Comment: And yet it is sometimes more useful to get the display where your window is displayed rather than the default one, and there are various methods for this on the pyglet `Window` object.